# Issues with OR operation in MDX command

Tags: mdx

I'm trying to run a base query against a cube with a `WHERE Group A OR Group B` syntax.  I've tried the code below based on articles online where the WHERE command needs a list, but it is failing to recognize the list:

```
SELECT FROM [Ticket] 
WHERE ([Analyst].[Group Name].&[IS Epic Service Desk],[Analyst].[Group Name].&[IS Service Desk])
```

In the current state it's giving an error that I'm trying to use same hierarchy more than once in the same Crossjoin. I've tried adding {} to isolate the statement but receive an out of range error.

The end goal is a query that returns matches for IS Epic Service Desk and IS Service Desk in the same list.

Answer (score 0):

The `()` in the `WHERE` clause indicates to analysis services that you want to specify a `tuple` - which is a single point within the cube space. Hence the error message you're getting as a single point in the cube cannot be defined using two members of the same hierarchy.

So we know that this is ok:

```
SELECT
... 
FROM [Ticket] 
WHERE ([Analyst].[Group Name].&[IS Epic Service Desk]);
```

As is this:

```
SELECT
... 
FROM [Ticket] 
WHERE ([Analyst].[Group Name].&[IS Service Desk]);
```

You mentioned using `{}` which is correct. I'm a little unsure where you put these braces but the following should implement `OR` logic:

```
SELECT
... 
FROM [Ticket] 
WHERE (
  {
    [Analyst].[Group Name].&[IS Service Desk]
   ,[Analyst].[Group Name].&[IS Epic Service Desk]
  }
 );
```

Generally in Boolean logic `OR` means is either X, or is Y, or is X and Y. I'm a little unsure if this definition of `OR` agrees with the final sentence of your question?

> The end goal is a query that returns matches for IS Epic Service Desk
>   and IS Service Desk in the same list.

The above almost sounds more like `AND` logic so you only want the data when it is Epic Service Desk and Service Desk. If that is the case then a cascading `NonEmpty` expression may suffice:

```
SELECT
... 
FROM [Ticket] 
WHERE (
  {
    NonEmpty(
      NonEmpty(
         [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
        ,[Analyst].[Group Name].&[IS Service Desk]
      )
   ,[Analyst].[Group Name].&[IS Epic Service Desk]
   )
 );
```